# xpath issue with selectSingleNode when switch to XML 6

Tags: xpath, selectsinglenode, msxml6

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Revision>
  <Revision Index="1"/>
</Revision>
```

When using `DomDocument(ver 3)` I could run the following(In VB6):

```
Set objNode = objDom.documentElement.selectSingleNode("//.[@Index = '1']")
```

This is to identify that this attribute exists with it's value.

Now after moving to `DomDocument60(ver 6)` this line fails.

How should I re-write it so it works with `DomDocument60`?

Thanks in advance
Doron

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the XPath:

```
//Revision[@Index="1"]
```

This will select all `Revision` nodes in the document that have the attribute `Index="1"`.

Comment: Great - if you are satisfied with the answer then please accept!